# Paasing variable of model class in Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass variable's value of model class in Ajax.ActionLink

I have tried like this.

View:

```
 <td>
      @Ajax.ActionLink("Event List", "EventList", "Member", new {contact_no = @Model.Cno, email = @Model.email}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })
 </td>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EventList(string contact_no,string email)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    { 
        //...
    }
}
```

Problem is It is taking null values.
Please give me solution for passing model value in controller using Ajax.ActionLink

Comment: are you sure Model.Email and Mode.Contact_no are not null in view?

Comment: Ya definitely, I am printing First Name using this model in same view

Comment: i am taliking about contact_no and Email do make sure these two are not inull

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong.

Due to putting `@Model.Property` inside `@Ajax.ActionLink()` it will not recognize model property.

Instead of this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Event List", 
                 "EventList", 
                 "Member", 
                  new {contact_no = @Model.Cno, 
                       email = @Model.email}, 
                  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })
```

so like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Event List", 
                     "EventList", 
                     "Member", 
                      new {contact_no = Model.Cno, 
                           email = Model.email}, 
                      new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })
```

Comment: No same issue, it is giving NULL in controller.

Comment: make sure CNo and email are not null in the model